# Application Loader: Apple's web service operation was not successful

Tags: ios, air, application-loader, flash-cs6

I'm trying to upload an app with `Application Loader` but I get following error :

> Apple's web service operation was not successful Unable to
>   authenticate the package: 54005906.itmsp An unknown error occurred.
>   (2010)

What is the problem? I really can't find any info.

Comment: Is this persistent, or have you only tried once?

Comment: Most likely one of your profiles or certificates are not valid. There are many things that might cause this. Have you checked them?

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827357/xcode5-apples-web-service-operation-was-not-successful/21330553#21330553

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its was problem with Apples process. Worked the day after!

Answer (score 1):

I would check following
1. Profile, username, password, certificate 2. Clean Build and Try again.

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting it for several days until I changed Deployment Target from 3.1.3 to 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

I just selected Standard Architectures in both Project and Target, and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error but fixed it by changing **Build Active Architecture Only** from

Release YES
to
Release NO.

Answer (score 0):

## When submitting a question like this you need to include all the error messages

If you choose to post only the error messages that you think are relevant, you are probably going to choose the wrong messages. If you know how to indentify the extraneous info, you probably don't need to post a question to StackOverflow at all. ;-)

## When submitting a question like this there are a few things to note:

### • If you submit enough failures in some given time frame, *Apple will stop allowing you to connect/submit* for some other time frame!

[image: No submit for you!]
- This is a situation that seems to correct itself overnight in most cases. You can use a different authorized account to get around this. (Create a new one if you gotta.)

### • The first 2 items are [red herrings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring)

[image: don't get caught up on "unable to authenticate"]

> **Apple's web service operation was not successful**

- In spite of how it sounds, this doesn't mean it couldn't connect. This simply means that the ultimate goal was not successful.
- As a metaphor: `if (ApplicationLoader.DeliverYourApp(SelectedFile)){log("Delivery Successful");} else {msg("Apple's web service operation was not successful");}`

> **Unable to authenticate the package: 81680085.itmsp**

- Before Apple accepts your package on their server, they want it to pass a few "field sobriety" checks.
- From their perspective, it's like "cloud computing". They are saving server resources by doing analysis in the cloud. And the cloud is the workstations of all their developer.apple.com members.

### • The "Background Activity" panel (revealed by clicking "Activity...") is very useful to watch.

Seeing "Could not start delivery: all transports failed diagnostics" makes you think there is some form of connection or login error (especially when combined with the top 2 errors. If you open the Background Activity panel early on and watch the entire process, you see that the message that is RED in the screenshot above actually goes through these states:

- Upload package to the iTunes Store
- Authenticating with the iTunes Store
- Verifying assets with the iTunes Store
- Could not start delivery: all transports failed diagnostics

---

### Finally, the error in my screenshot actually means...

The IPA file I was given fixes the bug that prevented my previous upload from succeeding, however, the developer forgot to increment the build number and Apple re-rejects it out of principle. This could be avoided if they would implement a build script that does something alone the lines of `git log --oneline | wc -l`. This is [pretty much exactly the way I do it](http://jomnius.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-autogenerate-app-version-number.html) in my projects.