# Xcode5: Apple's web service operation was not successful

Tags: upload, xcode5

it's return:

> 1、Apple's web service operation was not successful
>
> 2、Unable to authenticate the package:730904073.itmsp
>
> 3、ERRPR ITMS-9000:"This bundle is invalid.Apps that include an armv7s architecture are required to include an armv7 architecture."at SoftwareAsset/SoftwareAsset(MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)

but my "Build Settings","Architectures"is"Standard architectures(including 64-bit)(armv7,armv7s,arm64)".

And when I turn the "Architectures"to the "Standard architectures(armv7,armc7s)" it's same return.

In the past three days,it aways return me this error.

I really don't know what to do.
Please help me .

Answer (score 6):

OK,I got it !

I delete the “armv7s” in Valid Architectures both 'debug' and 'Release'.

And turn the 'Build Active Architecture Only' to 'No'

Then Apple receive it！

Answer (score 0):

I too faced same issues during App submission, I have resolved above problem by following steps

1) Go to Applications->Xcode->contents->Applications->Application Loader.app->Contents->MacOs->itms->java->lib there u will find a file **net.properties** open it with text edit and then change the line **# https.proxyPort=443**   with  **# https.proxyPort=80**

2) Quit Xcode and reopen after in build settings make it to Don't Code sign then clean the project

3) in the Build Active Architecture Only all values to NO

4) for Architectures select Standard architectures (including 64-bit)(armv7,armv7s,armv64)

```
   if don't have any images errors you can go ahead and archive and try to submit. if you have it then follow next steps
```

5) Go -Info.plist file in Xcode in supporting files in that file select icon file remove all the images if you have any thing

6)then clean project and reassign all images in General tab of the project(if u select Project title u can see this tab)

7) select appropriate Code signing identity and Provisiong profile and archive and submit to store