# Apple's web service operation was not successful and Unable to Authenticationthe package?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, itunesartwork

When I'm trying to upload an app with Application Loader but I get following error :

1. Apple's web service operation was not successful.
2. Unable to Authenticationthe package 787376632.itmsp
3. ERROR ITMS-9000:"Invalid Image Path _ No image found at the path referenced under key 'CGBundleIcons':'iTunesArtwork"" at Software/SoftwareAsset (MZItemspSoftwareAssetPackage)
4. ERROR ITMS-9000:"Invalid Image Path _ No image found at the path referenced under key 'CGBundleIcons':'iTunesArtwork@2x"" at Software/SoftwareAsset (MZItemspSoftwareAssetPackage)

Please any one help me

[image]

Comment: @Desdenova you have any idea?

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827357/xcode5-apples-web-service-operation-was-not-successful/21330553#21330553

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yesterday I was facing the same problem uploading a app in appStore. I get rid of these by doing the following:

1. Got to project setting. From there select general tab. Make sure your project bundle identifier is same as app identifier (that you created in app store). Bundle Identifier is under Identity tab.
   [image]
2. In App Icon select source " Use Asset Catalog". If you do so, App Icon will be changed into this.[image]
3. Click on the arrow sign this will take you here.
   [image]
4. Provide necessary image of specific size.

   Thats how I got rid of these error.

**EDIT**

For Xcode 4.6.1 if you want to change the bundle identifier do as follow:

1. From target go to Summary
   [image]
2. From target go to info
   [image]
3. From Resource info.plist
   [image]

For changing the app icon do as follow:

1. From target go to Summary.
   [image]
2. App Icon can be also add in target >> info >> Icon files
   [image]

Please find out where you are using the artworks. May be you changed the artwork or They are missing somehow. Let me know if it works. :)

Comment: @Aneesha>> You can see it in info >> icon files. I am also gonna add this, it may help others.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, doesn't worked neither even using the asset catalog for the icon. It was because despite of using it, at the same time a had a couple lines at my Info.plist indicating the names of the icons CFBundleIcons/Icon files, for example. After a lot of pain trying to find what was wrong, removing this lines worked for me.

Answer (score -7):

1. Disconnect the device first
2. Clean it
3. quit the xcode
4. reopen the project

And thats it , it will work now

Comment: This post is about App Store exportation, not device.